# How does the autocomplete work in most IDE? Do languages define a source code for the autocomplete? What about custom IDE or languages?

Tags: debugging, autocomplete

How does a language do the **autocomplete** or IntelliSense? For example Lua. Would that be in Lua's Source Code? Somewhere here https://github.com/lua/lua?

Or is it something that someone else had to create? And did they have to do it for every IDE?

And how did they do it? How did they avoid mistakes? How did they test it? How did they debug it?

Apparently, *"IntelliSense"* is a term for Microsoft's autocomplete. I am not sure what other IDEs call it. I am trying to make this a general question about autocomplete.

I've only heard about Language Server Protocol, but I don't know much about it. And is it even something you'd need a server for, or is it just called that? I don't think Visual Studio Code starts a server when I open it, or does it?

Are Language Server Protocols the only way, or the *supposed* way? Is any other method *bad* or *inefficient*?
How would it know that *something* has access to methods of *something*?

What about language modifications or custom languages? Or custom autocomplete implementations?